# Solubility Product, and it's relation to solubility

Tags: water, solubility, solutions, precipitation, separation-techniques

In order to remove temporary hardness of water, it is boiled.

On boiling, while Ca(HCO3)2 gives CaCo3(ppt.) , Mg(HCO3)2 gives Mg(OH)2(ppt.).

According to my book precipitation of Mg(OH)2 occurs due to it's *high solubility product*.

But doesn't a higher solubility product mean a higher solubility? (Since solubility product is the product of solubilities of each component)

Comment: Can you provide the exact full quote from the book?

Comment: it should be lower solubility product.

Comment: Is it an error in the book?

Comment: Yes. it is a mistake.